# Interpreting trees of XGBoostRegressor Model

Tags: machine-learning, boosting

I fitted a dmlc XGBoostRegressor model on a [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o_ESk660gw3Ci4H_RVJXRc9zCiKF0Zvx/view?usp=sharing) with the variables `['CPI', 'Fuel_Price', 'Temperature', 'Unemployment']` and `Weekly_Sales` as the target column.

On calling the `get_dump` method of the booster, I got this as the output

```
['0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329302.531\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329747.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330160.312\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329053.969\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329170.312\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329982.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329104.156\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329137.156\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330236.156\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329294.531\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329796.875\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329830.844\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328940.344\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328961.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329524.781\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329217.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329684.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329125.906\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328701.625\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329561.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329476.312\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329461.875\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328941.406\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329862.781\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329005.875\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329438.844\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329967.562\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330012.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330047.875\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329203.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329165.875\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330092.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328510.906\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328970.719\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329716.188\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328921.281\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329413.281\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329069.281\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329176.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329788.469\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329518.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328390.281\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329060.156\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330460.656\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330349.062\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329767.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330169.594\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329695.469\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329004.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328929.438\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329789.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329472.781\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329576.844\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329171.969\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328871.031\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328978.312\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330081.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328753.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329748.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330605.406\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329190.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329480.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328893.281\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329485.781\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329667.406\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330021.719\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328994.281\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329750.188\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329118.188\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329745.719\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329729.75\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329411.312\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328842.312\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329581\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329224.719\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329223.719\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329711.344\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=330098.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328747.219\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329718.844\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=328533.312\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329316.719\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329097.781\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329237.656\n',
 '0:leaf=0.0934955776,cover=329210.312\n']
```

None of the variables I used in training comes up in any of these trees and they are all leaf nodes.

How do I interpret this result? 
Also, in the first tree, what does `leaf=0.0934955776` and `cover=329302.531` indicate?

These are the hyperparameters I used

```
{'alpha': 0.09609812947036414, 'colsampleBytree': 0.3905334806558341, 'eta': 0.05993483819906295, 'gamma': 2.984254821230856, 'maxBin': 27, 'maxDeltaStep': 1.5599536434168235, 'maxDepth': 8, 'minChildWeight': 6458.3654299043665, 'numRound': 85, 'rateDrop': 0.08000474078175099, 'regLambda': 0.017965626423790668, 'scalePosWeight': 0.47964508064705125, 'skipDrop': 0.3637793984107442, 'subsample': 0.7815658127047251}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the "leaf" value, you might find an explanation [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/34449/get-dump-leaf-value-and-auc) or [here](https://www.kaggle.com/general/20322) and "cover" according to the documentation (see [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html)) is the average coverage of splits which use the feature where coverage is defined as the number of samples affected by the split.